# learning ranked instance similarity by machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, distance

Here there are many vectors with rank.

a = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 10,...)

b = c(4,2,3,2,8,...)
...

please note, here it's the rank of value but not the value itself in these vectors.

There are a few instances that are similar in practice. But have no information about the similarity computationally.

which machine learning method can be used to learning the similarity or distance between these ranked vectors? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of possibilities. Why not, for instance, a  simple distance meassure e.g. the manhatten distance? This one is defined as follows:

ManhattenDistance(X, Y) := dist(X, Y) = sum( |X[i] - Y[i]| ) for i = 1, 2, ..., n = length(X)

Comment: It seems Manhatten Distance fails to copy with rank.